# Handling form validation with Thymeleaf 3.x - Stylizing errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, thymeleaf

I'm testing for the first time Thymeleaf 3.x with a simples web app, and I'm having some issues doing form validation. I'm not able to change the graphical style of my form fields with the Thymeleaf attribute **th:errorclass**, and I don't know why.

Here is my **controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/" , "" , "/home" , "/index" , "/login"} , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLogin(final Model m)
{
    if(m.containsAttribute("login") == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Creating login form...");
        m.addAttribute("login", new For_Login());
    }

    return Util_Paginas.PAG_LOGIN.toString();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/login" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String authenticate(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("login") final For_Login form , 
        final BindingResult br , 
        final Model m)
{
    System.out.printf("Authentication received!%n");
    System.out.printf("LOGIN: %s%n" , form.getLogin());
    System.out.printf("PASS: %s%n" , form.getSenha());

    if(br.hasErrors())
    {
        System.out.printf("Found %d fields!%n" , br.getErrorCount());
    }

    return Util_Paginas.PAG_LOGIN.toString();
}
```

My **HTML file** with Thymeleaf 3.x nature:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" th:href="@{/css/estilos.css}" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>Welcome. Please login.</p>

        <form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" th:object="${login}" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    Login: 
                    <input 
                    type="text" 
                    th:field="*{login}" 
                    th:class="campo" 
                    th:errorclass="campo-invalido">
                </p>
                <p>
                    Password: 
                    <input 
                    type="password" 
                    th:field="*{senha}" 
                    th:class="campo" 
                    th:errorclass="campo-invalido">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

My **CSS file**:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

.campo
{
    background-color: gray;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.campo-invalido
{
    background-color : #ff0000;
    border: 1px solid #800000;
    width: 230px;
    color: white;
}

p
{
    color: blue;
    font-size: 22pt;
}
```

What is happening is that the style is not being applied. Errors are found on the server side, but when the page is returned, it is as if the th: errorclass attribute was not present. I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

I know that my css file is being read because the P tags are getting stylized.

I'm using:

- Eclipse Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
- thymeleaf 3.0.3 RELEASE
- thymeleaf-spring4 3.0.3 RELEASE
- spring-webmvc 4.1.1 RELEASE
- spring-context 4.1.1 RELEASE
- validation-api 1.1.0 FINAL
- hibernate-validator 5.3.4 FINAL

If in case someone wants to see some more code of my project, I'll be happy to present it here.

Thank you for your time and patience.

### EDIT

I almost forgot something important too, my Spring MVC Application Context file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- MAPEAMENTO DE RECURSOS -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->

    <!-- Mapeamento de recursos (arquivos css, fontes, imagens, dentre outros). -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/css/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/imagens/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/imagens/" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/fontes/**" location="/WEB-INF/recursos/fontes/" />

    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- ANOTAÇÕES E RECURSOS SPRING -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->

    <!-- Possibilita o uso de anotações Spring Mvc. -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Define local para procura de componentes Spring (beans configurados 
        por anotações em classes). -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.regra7.st.controle" />

    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- INTERNACIONALIZAÇÃO -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->



    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- CONFIGURAÇÕES DO THYMELEAF -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->

    <!-- Template Resolver para Template Engine. -->
    <!-- <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver"> 
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" /> <property name="suffix" 
        value=".html" /> <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" /> </bean> -->

    <!-- SpringResourceTemplateResolver automatically integrates with Spring's 
        own -->
    <!-- resource resolution infrastructure, which is highly recommended. -->
    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <!-- HTML is the default value, added here for the sake of clarity. -->
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <!-- Template cache is true by default. Set to false if you want -->
        <!-- templates to be automatically updated when modified. -->
        <property name="cacheable" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- SpringTemplateEngine automatically applies SpringStandardDialect and -->
    <!-- enables Spring's own MessageSource message resolution mechanisms. -->
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
        <!-- Enabling the SpringEL compiler with Spring 4.2.4 or newer can speed 
            up -->
        <!-- execution in most scenarios, but might be incompatible with specific -->
        <!-- cases when expressions in one template are reused across different 
            data -->
        <!-- ypes, so this flag is "false" by default for safer backwards -->
        <!-- compatibility. -->
        <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- CONFIGURAÇÕES DO SPRING MVC -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->

    <!-- View resolver do Thymeleaf. -->
    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Definição de HandlerMapping. -->
    <!-- Cuida de classes controladoras. -->
    <!-- <bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping"> 
        </bean> -->

    <!-- ################################################################################### -->
    <!-- INTERCEPTADORES -->
    <!-- ################################################################################### -->

    <!-- INTERCEPTADORES -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/usuario/*" />
            <bean class="com.regra7.st.interceptadores.Login" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

### EDIT 2

After messing around a bit with the validation code, I changed the approach used and suddenly, things started to work.

Previously, I was using bean validation with my own annotations for data validation. I decided to change to the validation done with Spring, using org.springframework.validation.Validator, And magically everything went well.

However, I would not like to use the data validation approach with Spring, but rather with bean validation annotations. I've figured out where I'm wrong, but I do not understand why.

I'll put my login validation code:

```
// My bean validation annotation.
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = Val_Login.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD , ElementType.FIELD , ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Login 
{
    String message() default "{com.regra7.st.login}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    int min() default 10;
    int max() default 20;
}

// Validator implementation.
public class Val_Login implements ConstraintValidator<Login , String>
{
    private int min;
    // private int max;

    @Override
    public void initialize(Login login)
    {
        this.min = login.min();
        // this.max = login.max();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) 
    {
        return Util_Validador.isLoginValido(value , this.min);
    }
}

// The form input object.
public class For_Login
{
    @Login(min = 8)
    private String login;

    // Many things ommited
}
```

The Util_Validador class is able to return a true or false value, this has already been tested. If I do this:

```
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.regra7.st.formularios.For_Login;
import com.regra7.st.util.Util_Texto;

public class ValidadorFormulario implements Validator 
{
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) 
    {
        return For_Login.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object objeto, Errors erros) 
    {
        For_Login log = (For_Login) objeto;

        if(Util_Texto.isVazia(log.getLogin()) ||
            log.getLogin().length() < 8)
        {
            erros.rejectValue("login", "Login errado!");
        }
        if(Util_Texto.isVazia(log.getSenha()) ||
            log.getSenha().length() < 14)
        {
            erros.rejectValue("senha", "Senha errada!");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works out. Can you guys help me a bit, please? I think this can help many people who get on the same place as me.

As always, thank you.

Comment: Trying returning a ModelAnd View, as return new ModelAndView(Util_Paginas.PAG_LOGIN.toString(), "login", form);  Change your method signature accordingly

Comment: @lane.maxwell. Hi! Thank you for your comment! So... I tried to do what you said, but unfortunately the result was the same.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Hey! I got more info. If you don't mind, and have some time, can you take a look, please? If you have no way to help me, would it be asking a lot if you can state my question to some friend of yours? I know I'm being annoying, I'm sorry... feel free to do whatever you want. Thank you. Thank you really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did two things wrong:

- I forgot to import some [libraries needed by Hibernate Validator](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted-uel).
- I was using prefixes for form fields (For_Login). The data binding
  was not happening properly. Actually, it was, but Thymeleaf was not
  recognizing it properly. It's no use having a field named _myField
  (for instance), and setting setMyField and getMyField methods. Either
  you write the field with the name myField, or the methods with the
  names get_myField and set_myField.